# jQuery conflict when removing div after page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to remove a div from the page (preferably prevent it from loading at all)
but for now I'm settling on removing it after the page loads.

When I try the following lines of code [in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fariskassim/FRYsJ/2/), the `#content` div gets removed, as expected.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
  $(window).load(function(){
      $('#content').remove();
  });//]]>  
</script>
```

However, I have also tried implementing it on [an actual website](http://stage.bravo-company.info/luchatest/), but in that case, the `#content` div isn't removed.

Any suggestions as to what might be wrong?

Comment: Note that [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) is deprecated as of jQuery 1.8.

Comment: why not remove it in $(document).ready(function(){

Answer (score 2):

If you're sharing jQuery with another library that uses the dollar for its operation you need to guard against it like this, using an anonymous wrapper:

```
(function($) {
    $(window).on('load', function(){
        $('#content').remove();
    });
}(jQuery));
```

*Note that instead of .load() I'm using .on('load', fn).*

Instead of on page load you could also bind your code on DOM ready; jQuery passes itself as the first argument to the inner function:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#content').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your $ variable does not point to jQuery for some reason.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    window.$ = jQuery;
    $(window).load(function()
    {

        $('#content').remove();
     });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var node = document.getElementById('content'); 
if(node.parentNode)
{ 
node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
}
</script>
```

Hope this help.

Comment: That code only empties the node content.

`(function(){
    var node = document.getElementById('content');
    if(node.parentNode) node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
}());`
Would be the correct code to remove a node.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
<script type='text/javascript'> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
         $('#content').remove();
    });
</script>
```

or

```
$(function()
{
        $('#content').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have a javascript error when you call `$(window).load()`.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'load'
```

Also, you should better use [document.ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) instead as the content will be removed faster (doesn't need to wait for all the images to load).

```
//shorthand for $(document).ready()
$(function(){
    $('#content').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

TypeError: $(...).load is not a function

It is giving error above instead of below one as load is deprecated in new version of Jquery

```
$(window).load(function(){
});
```

use this code

```
$(function(){
 // your code here
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using jQuery testing with onload,

so you have to add onload syntax in jquery, on your site the statement was not called onload, that why its not working

I have updated fiddle

```
http://jsfiddle.net/MarmeeK/FRYsJ/3/
```

The JS code under `<script>` tag, without adding in onload in page,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){$('#content').remove();});
</script>
```

this should work :)

Comment: hmm i tried this.. still doesnt work, i also tried replacing content removing other div ids or classes. but they still show. could it be a javascript error somewhere?

Comment: can you please update the page and paste link after this change.. Nice site are creating, but some other css may be over-ridding. The JS works fine unless there are two ID of same name check that first if you have doubts..

Answer (score 0):

Case of jquery conflict. You have mootools framework too on the page.

Also I did a 'view source' of the page and I found out this line

```
$j = jQuery.noConflict();  //line 132
```

So try this

```
$j('#content').remove();
Or
jQuery('#content').remove();
```